# Final newline character not seen by editors

Tags: python, append, editor, newline

I am parsing a file generated by this python script:

```
import sys
import random

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
try:
    filename, n_tuples = sys.argv[1:3]
    n = int(n_tuples)
except:
    print 'Usage: %s <outfile> <number of tuples>' % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(0)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for _ in xrange(n):
        row = []
        for a in range(100):
            row.append(''.join([random.choice(letters) for j in range(10)]))
        print >>f, ",".join(row)

print "Generated %d random tuples in %s." % (n, filename)
```

Called as follows:

```
python <script> <outfile> <number of tuples>
```

it generates 1000 lines of 100 comma-separated groups of ten characters that are displayed in various editors in the following format:

```
xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,...,xxxxxxxxxx\n
xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,...,xxxxxxxxxx\n
...
xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,...,xxxxxxxxxx <--final line: no terminating newline
```

However, the size of the output (ls -l outfile = 1100000) and my parser agree there is a newline at the end of the file.

If there is a newline at the end of this file, why might it not be "displayed" in the editors?

EDIT in response to comment from abamert:

Here is the output from the given call:

```
>> python <script> <outfile> 1000
Generated 1000 random tuples in <outfile>.
```

And here is the first 22 characters:

```
>> head -c 22 csv_file2
HLNLTACOFP,YLWASEJXIN,
```

Comment: `emacs` shows me a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: `vi` did not show a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: This isn't a complete program, and your input is clearly just going to print a `Usage` message. If you want us to debug your code, you have to give us a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to debug. (If you just patch this all up to work in the obvious way, it doesn't have the problem you describe in the first place, so presumably your actual example is different from this patched up to work in the obvious way.)

Comment: @abamert: This is the exact script. The full invocation is `python <scriptname> <outfile> <number of tuples>` in case you are wondering about the number of parameters it is parsing. Yoel already ran what I posted with no problems.  I guess I left out the import statements.  I will add those now.